# Is there any way to, within an object, have it "replace itself" with another object?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure this is possible, but I would love it if it was.  I have an instance of a class (i.e., an object) `a1`, and I want to be able to call a method within that object that suggests it replace itself with another object `a2`.  I truly want the original object (`a1`) to be `a2`, such that if you called `a1.GetHashCode()` within `Main()` it would be the same hash code as `a2`.

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static MyObject a2 = new MyObject(1000);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyObject a1 = new MyObject(1);      // Create an Object
        a1.ReplaceMe(ref a2);               // Try to replace it

        Console.WriteLine("X = " + a1.x);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    public int x;

    public MyObject(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void ReplaceMe(ref MyObject somethingElse)
    {
        this = somethingElse;   // REPLACE ITSELF?  (not allowed)
        return;                 // GAURANTEED TO DIRECTLY RETURN
    }
}
```

But obviously `this = somethingElse;` is not allowed since `this` is read only.  I understand why it's not allowed (who knows if execution were to complete), but I could guarantee you'd immediately return.

Is there any way around this?

---

**Edit:** More context on why I am looking for such a design through an example.  Here is the overall goal.  Imagine a platform that parses through data about people and when it finds information about it a person, it creates an instance of `Person` with that information.  You could get a handle do that person like:

```
Person person1 = platform.GetPerson(based_on_data);
```

Now, imagine the platform had two instances of `Person` that it thought were different people, but all of a sudden information came in that strongly suggested those two instances actually refer to the same person.  So, the platform wants to merge the instances together in to a new object, let's call it `personX`.

Now, floating around in the platform someone had a copy of one of those two instances that got merged, which was `person1`.  What I want to do is on-the-fly replace `person1` with `personX`. Literally, I want `person1==personX` to be true, NOT just that they are two different objects with the same data.

Since I can't on-the-fly replace `person1` with `personX` I had that idea that I wouldn't give direct access to `Person`, instead I would give access to `PersonPtr` which the platform (on-the-fly) can change what `Person` it is pointing to.

Comment: It sounds to me like an XY problem. Why would you need to do something like this? It sounds like you have a major design flaw (or a major misunderstanding of OOP) if there's a need to change an object type within its own methods.

Comment: Do the replacement in the context where your reference exists, e.g. as a property of another class, or in a method or whatever.

Comment: There is no way to replace `this` because it cannot be passed as a `ref` from C#.

Comment: No.  'a1' and 'a2' are just references.  what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: And the direct answer to the question asked is *No*. This would be like trying to switch the kind of airplane you're flying in while it's airborne while staying in your seat.

Comment: Actually there is a way with refection to scan all the members and then copy the values. I don't have an exact example of how to do it like this, but I do have the codes for scanning members and copying them. However the class has to be marked with Serializable attribute and all reference members such as class members has to be marked with it too. I will try to edit my code to make something like this working, give me a few minutes, if I can find time, else I will pastebin the codes for it. i am on a busy schedule right now sorry! :)

Comment: I suspect (by `GetHashCode` reference) you may be looking for `IComparer<T>` (assuming you want to search for something...)

Comment: why not just a1 = a2 ?... . if you set first to next hashcode will be the same... .

Comment: Juan it will only replace the reference.

Comment: @L33TS If you scan all the members and copy the values, you've managed to mutate another object to be identical to the `MyObject` instance in `a1`, but you still haven't managed to change what the reference `a1` points to from within a member of `MyObject`.

Comment: It might help to know what you're actually trying to accomplish.  I could see a few reasons why this would seem like the thing to do, and there is probably a good answer.

Comment: @L33TS - a copy-by-reflection alone won't satisfy the GetHashCode() requirement.

Comment: @KenWhite -- I'm not changing the "object type," right?  Here's a concrete example.  I create a bunch of objects that refer to people based on information that I find available.  All of a sudden, due to new information, I determine two of these people (objects) are actually the same.  Therefore I want to assign one to the other so that they are truly the same object.  I could end up creating a level of indirection like a "PersonPointer" where I could then decide "PersonPointer" points to the same PersonObject, deleting one of the real objects after merging. Wanted to avoid this.

Comment: @gnychis why do you want to avoid that?

Comment: After your __Edit__ it's even more of an XY question. After `replacing` person1  with person2 you would still have 2 independent, separately referenced instances. Your problems would only begin there.

Answer (score 1):

By "swapping out" one instance for another, what you essentially want to be able to do is assign a different value to the variable that contains the instance. One way to do this might be the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyObject a1 = null, a2 = null;

        MyObject.Create(i => a1 = i);
        MyObject.Create(i => a2 = i);

        Console.WriteLine("a1 hashcode:" + a1.GetHashCode()); // 46104728
        Console.WriteLine("a2 hashcode:" + a2.GetHashCode()); // 12289376

        a1.SwapWith(a2);

        Console.WriteLine("a1 hashcode:" + a1.GetHashCode()); // 12289376
        Console.WriteLine("a2 hashcode:" + a2.GetHashCode()); // 46104728
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    private Action<MyObject> _assigner;
    private MyObject() { }
    public static void Create(Action<MyObject> assigner = null)
    {
        var newInstance = new MyObject();
        newInstance._assigner = assigner;

        newInstance.Assign();
    }

    public void SwapWith(MyObject replacement)
    {
        replacement._assigner = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this._assigner, replacement._assigner);

        this.Assign();
        replacement.Assign();
    }

    private void Assign()
    {
        if (_assigner != null) _assigner(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think is possible; Why don't you make an static method (outside the MyObject class) with ref Object A and ref Object B as parameters?

```
static void replace(ref object a,ref object b)
{
a = b;
}
```

working code:

```
class Program
{
    static void replace(ref ObjectA a, ref ObjectA b) {
        a = b;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectA a = new ObjectA();
        ObjectA b = new ObjectA();
        Console.Write("a: " + a.GetHashCode() + "\n");
        Console.Write("b: " + b.GetHashCode() + "\n");
        Console.Read();
        replace(ref a, ref b);
        Console.Write("a: " + a.GetHashCode() + "\n");
        Console.Write("b: " + b.GetHashCode() + "\n");
        Console.Read();

    }
}
class ObjectA
{
}
```